# Calculate coefficient $z^n u^j$ of power series in two variables

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions

> I'm trying to calculate 
>   $$[z^n u^j] \frac{1}{(1-zu)(1-z)} \log \left(\frac{1}{1-zu}\right),$$ 
>   where $[z^n u^j] \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty F_{n,j} z^n u^j = F_{n,j}$.

So I have to calculate the coefficient of a generating function in two variables for $$\frac{1}{(1-zu)(1-z)} \log\left(\frac{1}{1-zu}\right).$$

As I know the series representation of $\frac{1}{(1-zu)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (uz)^n$, $\frac{1}{(1-z)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$, $\log \frac{1}{(1-zu)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(uz)^n}{n}$, I tried to build a cauchy product of the first and third series

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1-z)(1-zu)} \log \left(\frac{1}{1-zu}\right)&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n  \sum_{n=0}^\infty (uz)^n \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(uz)^n}{n}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{l=1}^k \frac{1}{l} u^k z^k\\  
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty H_k u^kz^{k+n}
\end{align}$$ 
but know I don't know how to go on. What could I do to get something in the form of 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty F_{n,j} z^n u^j\,?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. From your attempt it follows that
$$[z^n u^j] \frac{1}{(1-zu)(1-z)} \log \left(\frac{1}{1-zu}\right)
=\begin{cases}
H_j &\text{if $1\leq j\leq n$}\\
0   &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: How can I see that from my last equation?

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty H_k u^kz^{k+n}$ means that the coefficient of $u^kz^j$ is $H_k$ when $j=k+n\geq k$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: What would happen in the following case $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty H_k u^n z^{k+n}$?

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty H_k u^n z^{k+n}$ means that the coefficient of $u^nz^j$ is $H_{j-n}$ when $j=k+n≥n$ and $0$ otherwise